# Vuforia Engine failed to initialize on android in unity app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, vuforia

I created a unity project with vuforia engine 10.19.3, exporting and running it on android. The first time the app is started, it requests the missing camera permissions as expected and the engine gets initialized. No matter, if I select "only once" or "when using the app", the next time I start the app, there is no request for camera permissions and the app crashes with a vuforia engine initialization error (see logcat).

```
2024/01/04 16:02:17.120 21431 21451 Error AR 2024-01-04 16:02:17: Initialization of platform integration failed
2024/01/04 16:02:17.121 21431 21451 Error AR 2024-01-04 16:02:17: Creating Vuforia Engine instance...FAILED
2024/01/04 16:02:17.124 21431 21451 Error Unity Failed to create Vuforia engine: Unknown Vuforia Engine initialization error
2024/01/04 16:02:17.124 21431 21451 Error Unity UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
2024/01/04 16:02:17.124 21431 21451 Error Unity Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:InitOnCameraReady()
2024/01/04 16:02:17.124 21431 21451 Error Unity Vuforia.Internal.Utility.ExtensionMethods.IEnumerableExtensionMethods:ForEach(IEnumerable`1, Action`1)
2024/01/04 16:02:17.124 21431 21451 Error Unity Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:Init(String)
2024/01/04 16:02:17.124 21431 21451 Error Unity Vuforia.Internal.Core.OneTimeInitialization:Initialize()
2024/01/04 16:02:17.124 21431 21451 Error Unity 
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity Vuforia Engine initialization failed: PLATFORM_ANDROID_CONFIG_INITIALIZATION_ERROR
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity 
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity PLATFORM ANDROID CONFIG INITIALIZATION ERROR
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity 
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity Failed to initialize Vuforia Engine.
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity DefaultInitializationErrorHandler:SetErrorCode(VuforiaInitError)
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity DefaultInitializationErrorHandler:OnVuforiaInitializationError(VuforiaInitError)
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity System.Delegate:DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[])
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate(Delegate, Object[])
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling(Action`1, T)
2024/01/04 16:02:17.330 21431 21451 Error Unity
```

If I manually set the camera permissions to none in the android settings for the app, the next time I start the app, permissions get requested again and the engine initializes flawlessly.
If I manually change back to other settings then none, app crashes again with the same error.
So it only works once after I removed the camera permissions manually.

It seems, vuforia is not initializing correctly, when the app already has camera permissions.

Any ideas how to dig into it or even solve that behaviour / issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Retested with unity 2022.3 LTS (in comparison to 2023.2 originally), here the described effect is not happening. Seems to be an issue of unity in the newer version or in the combination of Vuforia 10.19.13 with unity 2023.x.

Would still be great to fiddle out, why that happens with the newer Unity Editor version.

Comment: I would file a bug here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I hadn't even noticed it was related to the camera permissions. But if I manually manipulate the permissions like you suggest I get the same behaviour. This is with Unity 2023.2.12f1 and Vuforia 10.21.3. Have you had any luck resolving this?

Comment: Not yet, I was falling back to LTS version 2022.3 for now.

Comment: I have filed a bug: https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/101 Lets hope this gets picked up

Comment: Vuforia developers are working on this and have provided a workaround: https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/101#issuecomment-2009926990